# ArrayList BinarySearch

Tags: java, binary-search

**question**

I want to implement a BinarySearch method myself on an Object of `Klant` how do i do this?
`Klant` has some variables.

```
public class Klant {
public String klantID;
private String voornaam;
private String tussenvoegsel;
private String achternaam;
private int leeftijd;
private static boolean MAN = true;
private String plaats;
private String email;
/*
 *  Getters and setters included 
 */
}

Klant toevoeging = new Klant("FirstName", "middleName", "\Lastname\"", 20, false, "Location", "email@email.com");
klanten.add(toevoeging);
```

Comment: I have posted an answer that I think suits your needs, although your requirements are not exactly clear. Be sure to write more extensive posts in future. Have a read of the [**Asking** section on the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for advice on asking easy to answer questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using Collections.binarySearch(...)

When you run a `Collections.binarySearch(...);` on a list the objects in that list must either `implement` [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or you will have to pass a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) into the `binarySearch(...)` method;

Using a Comparator as an example you could do the following;

```
class KlantComparator implements Comparator<Klant> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Klant o1, Klant o2) {
        if(condition)
          return 1;
        else if(condition2)
          return 0;
        else 
          return -1;
    }
}
```

In the above you compare the `Klant` objects `o1` and `o2` and return 1 if `o1` should be ranked higher than `o2`, return 0 if they are the same, and return -1 if `o1` is ranked lower than `o2`. And then to run the binary search;

```
    KlantComparator kc = new KlantComparator();
    ArrayList klants = new ArrayList<Klant>();
    Klant o = new Klant();
    klants.add(o);
    klants.add(new Klant());
    klants.add(new Klant());
    Collections.sort(klants, kc);
    Collections.binarySearch(klants, o, kc);
```

In the above please note that **the `klants` collection needs to be sorted first**, and that the binarySearch needs to be performed using the same `Comparator` that sorted the list.

I hope this helps.

Further Reading;

- [Collections API - binarySearch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator))
- [Comparator API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [Comparable API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to implement it yourself, [Collections.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) isnt good enough for you?

Okay....

Binary Search:

you have a **sorted** list. Get the element in the middle and compare with the Object in question. if it is **lower** than the element you want to find, repeat the search in the part of the list, which has only **higher** elements. If it is **higher**, search in the list part with only **lower** elements.

So how do you do binary search?

You need a measure, which defines for 2 object what the lower one and what the higher one is.

Your object must implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) **or**  you must define a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your list.

Then you need to actually sort the list. Sorting would be `Collections.sort(myList)`.

Now List has the `size()` method, which will help you determine the first "middle" element.

Pseudocode :

```
 **input** : keyElement

 startIndex = 0;
 endIndex = list.size();

 midIndex = (endIndex+startIndex) / 2;
 while(list.get(midIndex) !=  keyElement) {
     if (list.get(midIndex) < keyElement) {
         startIndex = midIndex;
     } else {
         endIndex = midIndex;
     }
     midIndex = (endIndex+startIndex) / 2;
 }

 return midIndex;
```

Something along those lines (be careful with boundaries here... maybe a +/-1 is needed.)